# Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined using webpack with load-google-maps-api-2

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-places-api

I'm attempting to set up an auto complete using  using maps javascript api place autocomplete but I keep receiving.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete'
>   of undefined

index.js

```
var loadGoogleMapsApi = require('load-google-maps-api-2');
const indexTemplate = require("./index.handlebars");

    $(function() {

        let googleMaps = null;

        loadGoogleMapsApi({
            key: 'My api key here'
        }).then(function(_googleMaps) {
            googleMaps = _googleMaps
            var autocomplete = new googleMaps.places.Autocomplete($("#address")[0]);

                googleMaps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                    console.log(place.address_components);
            });
        });
```

the full listing is here.

https://github.com/bryandellinger/addressvalidator

if you would like to run it after downloading
npm install
npm run build (do a webpack build)
npm run start (start lite server and open up browser on port 3000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to load the `places` library; according to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/load-google-maps-api):

```
loadGoogleMapsApi({
    libraries: ['places'],
    key: '...'
})
.then(function (googleMaps) {
  ...
})
.catch(function (error) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but when I added the class "pac-input" to my <input> tag, it started working.